# Google Play Service, can i expect the most recent version?

Tags: android, google-play-services

So the new Google Play Service 4.0 just got released and i was asking myself if i can use it instantly without problems in my app.

The question is: Can i expect that most of the user of my soon to be released app to have a updated google play version? 
Is this update mandatory for all users with API 2.3 and above as soon as they try to open the Play Store?
I integrated the new version into my app, and it got closed with a exception. Is there a way to handle this exception?

I already have the: `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);`
check.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that is feasible. however you can check if the version of the google play service is up to date with [SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED)

Comment: Jeah definitly a step into the right direction. I guess because this exists, there is no guarantee that the user will have the most recent version. Thats too bad. Thanks a lot